# Removing duplicate item in an ASP CheckBoxList using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `CheckBoxList` control on my web page. I have the property `AppendDataBoundItems="True"`

On PostBack the `CheckBoxList` retains the checked items, but appends a duplicate list of items to the existing CheckBoxList

If I set the property `AppendDataBoundItems="False"`, on `PostBack` the boxes checked are lost, but the dupicate items list is not appended.

How can I retain the checked items on PostBack and get rid of the duplicates in the list that are added on `PostBack`?

Do I need to hold the checked values in an array, and then use that to reselect the items in the `CheckBoxList`?

Comment: Can we see some of the code used for populating the CheckBoxList?

Comment: It sounds like you're re-binding the list on every page load.  Only bind it once on the initial load and let the view state hold the items.

Comment: don't rebind the `CheckBoxList` on postback.

Comment: David and DLeh, thanks for the simple solution. I thought I needed to rebind after PostBack, but it isn't needed at all. I appreciate the quick responses to my question.